# offsetTop issue in IE with parent elements

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, offset

I have an input field inside a div. When I set the div's style property to display:none, then the input inside the div must return offsetTop == 0. This is the case in FF, Opera, Safari and others, but not IE.

After several hours of research I failed to locate a method to check if a nested element is visible or not in IE.

p.s. Javascript Problem

Comment: Could you provide code example

Comment: Certain IE builds have a node's `parentNode` as the `offsetParent` instead of the body tag.

Comment: I don't think browsers *must* return 0. I think this edge case in defined in the specifications, and browsers will just do as they see fit. My guess is IE caches the rendering info so when you remove display:none the element can be drawn quicker. Just deal with it some other way

Answer (score 0):

This is why people use a javascript framework.

Here is how I check this in jQuery:

```
$(element).is(":visible")
```

Without jQuery I think you can do:

```
element.style.display === "none"
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Prototype.js and its visibility methods do not support this behavior for nested elements.